# texas holdem question on split pot

Tags: texas-hold-em

if the 5 cards out after the river show Ace, 10, 7, 5 and 2 flush of hearts and (player 1) has 4 of hearts and (player 2) has 8 of hearts , who wins hand or is it a split pot

Comment: Thanks for your Q Umbro Kid, If you search on this site for the "Top Five Card" rule you'll find the answers about split pots what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Player 2 will win. It is always the best 5 card hand.

Player 2's hand: A♥T♥8♥7♥5♥

Player 1's hand: A♥T♥7♥5♥4♥

Comment: and likewise, the board doesn't show the nut flush... either player holding the king of hearts would hold the nut flush.